# detect an initial/a sketch drawing on a text page

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to get the coordinates of the box around the initial ("H") on the following page (and similar ones with other initials, so opencv template matching is not an option):

[image]

Following [this](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/contour-detection-opencv-python) tutorial, I tried to solve the problem with opencv contours:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

page = "image.jpg"

# read the image
image = cv2.imread(page)

# convert to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0,150,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw all contours
image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.savefig("result.png")
```

The result is of course not exactly what I wanted:

[image]

Does anyone know of an viable algorithm (and possibly an implementation thereof) that could provide an easy solution to my task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the target area by **filtering** your contours. Now, there's at least two filtering criteria that you can use. One is filter by `area` - that is, discard *too small* and *too large* contours until you get the contour you are looking for. The other one is by computing the `extent` of every contour. The `extent` is the *ratio* of the contour's area to its bounding rectangle area. You are looking for a square-like contour, so its `extent` should be close to `1.0`.

Let's see the code:

```
# imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
# Deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get binary image via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

The first portion of the code gets you a binary image that you can use as a mask to compute contours:

[image]

Now, let's filter contours. Let's use the `area` approach first. You need to define a range of `minimum area` and `maximum area` to filter everything that does not fall  in this range. I've *heuristically* determined a range of areas from `30000` px to `150000` px:

```
# Find the contours on the binary image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Look for the outer bounding boxes (no children):
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob area:
    currentArea = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print("Contour Area: "+str(currentArea))

    # Set an area range:
    minArea = 30000
    maxArea = 150000

    if minArea < currentArea < maxArea:

        # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
        boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
        rectX = boundRect[0]
        rectY = boundRect[1]
        rectWidth = boundRect[2]
        rectHeight = boundRect[3]

        # Set bounding rect:
        color = (0, 0, 255)
        cv2.rectangle( inputImageCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                       (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2 )

        cv2.imshow("Rectangles", inputImageCopy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Once you successfully filter the area, you can then compute the `bounding rectangle` of the contour with `cv2.boundingRect`. You can retrieve the bounding rectangle's `x`, `y` (top left) coordinates as well as its `width` and `height`. After that just draw the rectangle on a deep copy of the original input.

Now, let's see the second option, using the contour's `extent`. The `for` loop gets modified as follows:

```
# Look for the outer bounding boxes (no children):
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob area:
    currentArea = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Calculate extent:
    extent = float(currentArea)/(rectWidth *rectHeight)
    print("Extent: " + str(extent))

    # Set the extent filter, look for an extent close to 1.0:
    delta = abs(1.0 - extent)
    epsilon = 0.1

    if delta < epsilon:

        # Set bounding rect:
        color = (0, 0, 255)
        cv2.rectangle( inputImageCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                       (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2 )

        cv2.imshow("Rectangles", inputImageCopy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Both approaches yield this result:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you ! When running the code on other similar images, however, I get a considerable number of false positives with `cv2.boundingRect(c)` = x0,y0, <imageWidth>, <imageHeight>. I cannot see which parameters I have to tweak in order to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: @AlexW. If you are implementing the area filter, you can tweak `minArea` and `maxArea` two re-define the area range. If you are implementing the extent filter, you can tweak `epsilon` to allow a more "relaxed" filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it. You just need to filter contours on area and aspect ratio. Here is my approach in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('syriados.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary
#thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert threshold
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply morphology to remove small white regions and to close the rectangle boundary
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# find contours
result = img.copy()
cntrs = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# filter on area and aspect ratio
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if area > 10000 and abs(w-h) < 100:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], 0, (0,0,255), 2)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("syriados_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("syriados_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("syriados_box.jpg", result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology image:

[image]

Resulting contour image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get a result like this:

[image]

You'll need to detect the contour in the image with the second to the greatest area, as the one possessing the greatest area would be the border of the image.

So with the list of contours, we can get the one with the second greatest area via the built-in `sorted` method, using the `cv2.contourArea` method as the custom key:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (7, 7), 2)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 50, 50)
    kernel = np.ones((6, 6))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=1)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=2)
    return img_erode

def get_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-2]
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02 * peri, True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

page = "image.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(page)
get_contours(image)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The above only puts the area of the contours into consideration; if you want more reliable results, you can make it so that it will only detect contours that are 4-sided.